# react testing library toHaveBeenCalledTimes checkbox test failing

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, ts-jest

I started to create unit tests using Jest & react-testing-library
I'm not sure Why is this failing:

```
Component:

const CheckboxInput: React.FC<Props> = ({ id, color, height, width, border, isChecked, handleChange 
     }) => {
       return(
           <input aria-label="checkbox-input" type="checkbox" checked={isChecked} onChange={(e) 
                   =>handleChange(id, e)} />
       )
   }
```

Test:

```
describe('Test CheckboxInput component', () => {
afterEach(cleanup);
const handleChangeMock = jest.fn();
const setup = () => {
    const utils = render(
        <CheckboxInput
            id={1}
            color={'#000'}
            height={'15px'}
            width={'15px'}
            border={'1px solid #000'}
            isChecked={false}
            handleChange={handleChangeMock}
        />,
    );
    const input = utils.getByLabelText('checkbox-input') as HTMLInputElement;
    return {
        input,
        ...utils,
    };
};
test('CheckboxInput initial value ', () => {
    const { input } = setup();
    expect(input.checked).toBe(false);

    fireEvent.change(input, { target: { checked: true } });

    expect(input.checked).toBe(true);
    expect(handleChangeMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
   });
});
```

It fails on toHaveBeenCalledTimes
[image]

Any insight will be much appreciated

Comment: is your `onChange` firing normally during manual testing?

Comment: Yes. The onChange method works on manual testing

Comment: @Shira added an working code sandbox . open the sandbox and visit the `tests` tab .

Answer (score -2):

You should simulate the checkbox checked event with

```
 fireEvent.click(input);
```

Also since you are testing the component in isolation , this will fail as your `isChecked` is always `false` . So please remove this

```
 expect(input.checked).toBe(true);
```

Change the `test` block to this

```
 test('CheckboxInput initial value ', () => {
    const {input} = setup();
    expect(input.checked).toBe(false);

    fireEvent.click(input);

    expect(handleChangeMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(handleChangeMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1, true);
  });
```

Working Example - [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jest-testing-react-forked-2j1sd?file=/src/components/CheckBox.test.js)

Comment: Are you getting any errors ? I posted this answer only after running through myself once . It worked fine without any issues .

Comment: @Shira Edited the answer . Have attached a working Code Sandbox . You can visit the `tests` tab .

Comment: I don't see how this has value -- sure, the sandbox test works, but only by overriding the code under test with a mock. It's not testing the real code, only the sample in the test itself.